# How to use a local variable within HTML in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, gatsby

How can I use a local var like `meta=data.site.siteMetadata` in Gatsby code below? Var/Const/$ do not seem to work. I want to use this `meta` var instead of `data`

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

export default ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>About {data.site.siteMetadata.title}</h1>
    <p>We're a very cool website you should return to often.</p>
  </div>
)

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

How can I make below work:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

export default ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    {var meta=data.site.siteMetadata}
    <h1>About {meta.title}</h1>
    <p>We're a very cool website you should return to often.</p>
  </div>
)

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: I couldn't understand the question, which local `var`? Please show the desired code you want to work with

Comment: @DennisVash - Sorry about not being clear. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question is about `React` and not `Gatsby` specific:

A simple example of how to use a local variable in a functional component:

```
const MyComponent = ({ data }) => {
  const myLocalVariable = data.site.siteMetadata.title;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>About {myLocalVariable}</h1>
      <p>We're a very cool website you should return to often.</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

For more specifics, your `graphql` query will return the next object:

```
{
  "data": {
    "site": {
      "siteMetadata": {
        "title": "My Site Title"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So in your case, you can do something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';

export default ({ data }) => {
  // meta is an object.
  const meta = data.site.siteMetadata;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>About {meta.title}</h1>
      <p>We're a very cool website you should return to often.</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

You should read the [**Getting Started**](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) section in react docs, **Gatsby** is a site generator for React so it's important to get to know all React concept beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing right. but, just need to replace the return method.

old :

```
   export default ({ data }) => (
      <div>
        {var meta=data.site.siteMetadata}
        <h1>About {meta.title}</h1>
        <p>We're a very cool website you should return to often.</p>
      </div>
    )
```

new :

```
   export default ({ data }) => {
    var meta= data.site.siteMetadata;
    return (
     <div>
        <h1>About {meta.title}</h1>
        <p>We're a very cool website you should return to often.</p>
      </div>
     )
    }
```

`=> ()` // this syntax in function just return the exact what you written inside this.

Just replace this with

```
=> { 
// Here you can define the variables
return ()
}
```